# Python GeoPandas: incorrect distance between point and line with same equidistant projection

Tags: python, distance, geopandas

I have two KML files:

1. One with a bunch of lines following some highways in the UK
2. Another with locations of sensors

I read both KMLs using GeoPandas. The CRS of these is stored in the KML, and from what I can see they are both in WGS84.

```
lines = gpd.read_file("overview.kml")

    Name                                                              Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                geometry
0    1  nr: 1 route: 0 skv: 0.96763647 slope: -0.8012349 height: 49.5044518 type: 1  LINESTRING Z (-2.35989 51.99732 49.76914, -2.35988 51.99730 0.00000, -2.35986 51.99728 0.00000, -2.35985 51.99726 0.00000, -2.35985 51.99725 0.00000, -2.35983 51.99723 0.00000, -2.35982 51.99720 0.00000, -2.35982 51.99720 0.00000, -2.35981 51.99719 0.00000, -2.35981 51.99717 49.50445, -2.35981 51.99715 0.00000, -2.35980 51.99712 0.00000, -2.35980 51.99710 0.00000, -2.35979 51.99708 0.00000, -2.35979 51.99705 0.00000, -2.35978 51.99703 0.00000, -2.35978 51.99701 0.00000, -2.35978 51.99699 49.23976)
1    2   nr: 2 route: 0 skv: 0.9573723 slope: -2.3243904 height: 49.0199852 type: 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 LINESTRING Z (-2.35978 51.99699 49.23976, -2.35977 51.99696 0.00000, -2.35977 51.99694 49.01999, -2.35977 51.99694 0.00000, -2.35977 51.99693 48.80021)
2    3  nr: 3 route: 0 skv: 0.96148646 slope: -1.4549532 height: 48.7746658 type: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   LINESTRING Z (-2.35977 51.99693 48.80021, -2.35977 51.99692 48.77467)
3    4   nr: 4 route: 0 skv: 0.96148646 slope: -3.195057 height: 48.6562519 type: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   LINESTRING Z (-2.35977 51.99692 48.74912, -2.35978 51.99690 48.65625)
4    5  nr: 5 route: 0 skv: 0.96148646 slope: -2.6707158 height: 48.2445383 type: 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      LINESTRING Z (-2.35978 51.99690 48.65625, -2.35978 51.99688 0.00000, -2.35979 51.99685 0.00000, -2.35980 51.99683 48.24454, -2.35980 51.99681 0.00000, -2.35981 51.99679 47.83282)


sensors = gpd.read_file("sensors.kml")

    Name            Description                           geometry
0   1303371 A5 Oswestry @ 110 m POINT Z (-3.03420 52.86870 0.00000)
1   1303460 A5 Grendon @ 80 m   POINT Z (-1.59550 52.59200 0.00000)
2   1303463 A38 Burton @ 45 m   POINT Z (-1.63650 52.82200 0.00000)
3   1303477 M50 Dymock @ 35 m   POINT Z (-2.40380 51.98450 0.00000)
4   1303478 M5 Chapmans Hill @ 210 m    POINT Z (-2.05380 52.39620 0.00000)
5   1303479 M6 Shareshill @ 107 m   POINT Z (-2.09170 52.67920 0.00000)
6   1303481 A49 Brimfield @ 100 m   POINT Z (-2.69800 52.29580 0.00000)
7   1303482 A46 Marraway @ 92 m POINT Z (-1.65300 52.24170 0.00000)
8   1303483 M42 Solihull MP28/7 N/B @ 111 m POINT Z (-1.72780 52.41370 0.00000)
9   1303661 M42 - Cheswick Green MP 21/7 N/B @ 125 m    POINT Z (-1.79370 52.36970 0.00000)
10  1303687 M6 - Little Madeley @ 110 m POINT Z (-2.32420 53.00220 0.00000)
11  1303759 M6 Walsall @ 115 m  POINT Z (-1.91510 52.54340 0.00000)
12  1399000 Grendon A5 @ 82 m   POINT Z (-1.59120 52.59070 0.00000)
```

For each sensor, I need to figure out if they are **on** the highway. I'm doing this by determining the minimum distance from each sensor to the set of lines:

```
pd.DataFrame({"Name": stations["Name"],
              "distance": pd.Series([gpd.GeoDataFrame(stationrow.to_frame().T, 
                                    geometry="geometry", crs=stations.crs).to_crs(32663)
                                    .distance(route)
                                    .dropna().drop_duplicates()
                                    for _, stationrow in stations.iterrows()])})

    Name    distance
0   1303371 107223.943075
1   1303460 84243.869474
2   1303463 104129.936521
3   1303477 3322.594544
4   1303478 49091.287628
5   1303479 78072.996411
6   1303481 40519.802479
7   1303482 55543.654363
8   1303483 63382.254866
9   1303661 56746.579637
10  1303687 111900.660355
11  1303759 67987.245547
12  1399000 84365.908542
```

but I don't trust the results. Opening both KMLs in Google Earth shows at least one sensor is very close

[image]

but the distances I'm getting are > 3000 (with EPSG:27700 should mean > 3km), or > 5000 when using WGS 84 / World Equidistant Cylindrical (EPSG:32663)

Even worse, when I convert the lines to a MultiLineString and do the distances again (with correct CRS):

```
sensors[sensors["Name"].eq("1303477")].to_crs(27700).distance(shapely.ops.asMultiLineString(lines.to_crs(27700)["geometry"])).dropna()
```

results in a distance of a little over 8m, which seems what I'm looking for...

Why does the distance depend on the type of geometry, and why do my distances seem so far off without aggregating them to a MultiLineString?

EPSG:27700:

[image]

Comment: You are dropping duplicates without sorting so the distance will not be the shortest distance?

Comment: @BERA Pretty sure pandas does some sorting before removing duplicates, how else would it determine duplicates efficiently? Also, I'm only dropping duplicates **after** determining the distance, so if the minimum distance has a duplicate value somewhere it would still show up. Nevertheless, without dropping duplicates I get the same incorrect result...

Comment: It will keep whatever distance that comes first. The first distance measured for each point